# find specific object from array of objects javascript ES

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
CoreMongooseArray [
0|index    |   { nCharge: 50,
0|index    |     _id: 5b603aa7d83da04a6db5751e,
0|index    |     nState: 1,
0|index    |     nIndex: 0,
0|index    |     sType: 'standard',
0|index    |     sAutoRecharge: true },
0|index    |   { nCharge: 50,
0|index    |     _id: 5b603aa7d83da04a6db5751f,
0|index    |     nState: -1,
0|index    |     nIndex: 1,
0|index    |     sType: 'standard',
0|index    |     sAutoRecharge: true },
0|index    |   { nCharge: 50,
0|index    |     _id: 5b603aa7d83da04a6db57520,
0|index    |     nState: -1,
0|index    |     nIndex: 2,
0|index    |     sType: 'standard',
0|index    |     sAutoRecharge: true }]



 cueModel.findOne({
    iUserId: req.body.iUserID
  }, (err, cue) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var cd =  cue.aCue;
    let c = cd.filter(o => {
      return o._id === req.body.cueId
    });
    return res.status(200).jsonp({
      "data": c
    });
  })
```

I want to find a specific object by `id`.
`let c = cd.find(o => o._id === req.body.cueId);`

above snippet working with normal array but not with CoreMongooseArray.
whats the differance

Comment: could you show your query

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet please check

Comment: `findOne` doesn't return array and that's why you cannot use `filter` here... you need to use `find` instead